# ¿Por qué al momento de imprimir el resultado no imprime verdadero o falso?

Tags: python

Estoy desarrollando un automata que valide si es o no un número entero o un número real para eso use distintos métodos y tengo un estado de error y otro de aceptación que devuelve un verdadero o falso si es que la cadena es aceptada, soy nuevo en python y quisiera saber en que parte estoy mal en la clase inicio

```
TT_NUMEROS = '0123456789'
class inicio():
    def __init__(self, contador, cadena):
    self.contador = 0
    self.cadena = cadena

    def numeroEntero(self):
        print("Entero")
        if self.contador < len(self.cadena):
            if self.cadena[contador] in TT_NUMEROS:
                contador += 1
                numeroEntero(self)
            elif self.cadena[contador] == '.':
                contador += 1
                numeroReal(self)

    def numeroReal(self):
        print("Real")
        if self.contador < len(self.cadena):
            if self.cadena[contador] in TT_NUMEROS:
                contador += 1
                numeroReal(self)
                return True
            elif not (self.cadena[contador] in TT_NUMEROS):
                contador += 1
                errorNumerico(self)

    def errorNumerico(self):
        return False
```

y en el principal tengo esto:

```
import automatas
with open('texto.txt', 'r') as f:
text = f.read()
siEs = automatas.inicio(0,text)
print(siEs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que no llamas a ningún método de la clase `inicio`, creas la instancia de esa clase, pero si no llamas a ningún método de esa clase no te devolverá ningún valor booleano.

Primero deberías crear una instancia de la clase `inicio` del siguiente modo:

```
nombreQueQuierasPoner = inicio(0, text)
```

despúes, si quieres llamar a alguna de los métodos deberías hacerlo así:

```
nombreQueQuierasPoner.númeroEntero()
```

ésto llamaría al método de instancia `númeroEntero`.

Ahora, si quieres llamar a alguno de los métodos desde dentro de la clase se hace así:

```
self.numeroReal()
```

y no:

```
numeroReal(self)
```

y si quieres acceder a alguno de las dos atributos `contador` y `cadena` dentro de un método de instancia debes acceder así:

```
self.contador
```

y no así:

```
contador
```

ya que te dirá que la variable local no no está asignada.